# scenebuilder cellfactory classnotfound exception

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Every time i try to open a fxml(with custom cellfactory in it) with scenebuilder 2.0 it throw a exception cellfactory class notfound. i've searched google whole morning but didn't find any solution for this. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I　tried out the solution myself, and i hope can help every body who are using sceneBuilder.

the solution : open your scenebuilder 2.0 install folder for example(C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0) then open edit the file  #sceneBuilder\app\package.cfg

append your project path(for those who use eclipse #project_path/bin) to app.classpath proerty for me(app.classpath=SceneBuilderKit.jar; C:/Users/shuku/Desktop/huping/work/fxServer/bin)

save try again, everything is fine!!!

Comment: try this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207087/scene-builder-cant-open-a-fxml-file