# Scene Builder can't open a FXML file

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using Gluon Scene builder 8 with NetBeans 8.2
When I double click a FXML file, an error appears saying: "Could not open Home.fxml"

Here is more details about the error
    java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    /home/hassen/Desktop/PiD/Outdoors2.0/src/edu/esprit/outdoors/gui/Home.fxml

```
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:82)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:97)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2384)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:664)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:385)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:634)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.access$200(SceneBuilderApp.java:84)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$1.invalidated(SceneBuilderApp.java:496)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.UserLibrary.lambda$updateFirstExplorationCompleted$7(UserLibrary.java:324)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/hassen/Desktop/PiD/Outdoors2.0/src/edu/esprit/outdoors/gui/Home.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDrawer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 27 more
```

Any help would be appreciated .. Thank you!

Comment: Show your code that loads the fxml file.

Comment: This error could also come from not having added the JFoenix library as a dependancy to your Java project. Remember, SceneBuilder and Java has separate dependencies

Comment: @Gikkman, exactly, thanks buddy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is a missing class: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDrawer

Did you put that library into the Scene Builder by hitting the library options -> "Import JAR/FXML file ..." or "Custom Library Folder" -> "Reveal in Explorer"?

[JavaFX Scene Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrEIR.png)