# JavaFX SceneBuilder cant open fxml document with an fx:include

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a JavaFX Application that I am building with SceneBuilder, I just found out about the nifty fx:include tag that allows you include FXML files into others.  I have one main FXML doc called Manager.fxml, this is a simple view with a header and a TabPane.  Each tab in the TabPane has its own fxml document and controller - messages, contacts, and products.

Here is the section of the code that is causing SceneBuilder to think its an invalid fxml file, specifically the fx:include part, if I remove that it works.  It even works in Java code if I inject the tab and set its content to the loaded FXML I am trying to include below.

```
<TabPane id="theTabs" prefHeight="849.0" prefWidth="1200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
    <tabs>
      <Tab text="System Messages">
        <content>
           <fx:include source="/fxml/manager_message_tab2.fxml" fx:id="systemMessage" />
        </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab fx:id="productsTab" onSelectionChanged="#goToProducts" text="Product" >
        <content>
           <fx:include source="/fxml/manager_products_tab.fxml" fx:id="product" />
        </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab fx:id="contactsTab" onSelectionChanged="#goToContacts" text="Contact">
        <content>
           <fx:include source="/fxml/manager_contacts_tab.fxml" fx:id="contact" />
        </content>
      </Tab>
    </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Althought SceneBuilder says its invalid, eclipse is able run it no problem.  I have tried using the built in tool in SceneBuilder 2.0 using File -> Include -> FXML but that fails also with - "Failed to include fxml_document.fxml under 'Tab'".  Root node of manager.fxml is a BorderPane - the root node of all the includes is also a BorderPane, so I am trying to include a border pane as the center element of a border pane.  Scenebuilder lets me drag a an empty border pane where I want it but doesn't let me fx:include one.

But that is exactly how I structured it when manually, as you can see in the code above.

My problem now is that if I try to open my manually edited FXML (the one with the included fx:include tags) it says its an invalid file and I cant edit it.

Anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Have you tried updating SceneBuilder?

Comment: No I wasn't even aware that the project had changed, downloading OpenFX now.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem, but it's a first step. [Gluon SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) now maintains SceneBuilder.

Comment: I just got the newest SceneBuilder from Gluon, 8.3 still with the same issue.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207087/scene-builder-cant-open-a-fxml-file

Comment: did you added custom library in sceneBuilder ? if yes,verify if your sceneBuilder has this library or no.